# kivy: ImportError: No module named app

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, kivy

I just installed [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home) by following the steps mentioned on the official documentation.

So I tried to test if it works by running an [example](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html) found on the official documentation:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label   

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

However, I got this error:

```
begueradj@begueradj-hacker:~# python kivy.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kivy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import kivy
  File "/root/kivy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
ImportError: No module named app
```

Installation went ok, so why is this problem ?

Comment: What happens if you add the require thats also in the example?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You named your file `kivy.py`. Rename it to something else. You are importing from your file not the kivy package. Make sure to delete any `.pyc` file also.

Comment: you also can't name the file run.py

Comment: haha. Did the same thing. Didn't even think about that!